# Servlet, GET and POST form problems

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with only one servlet, all the others (declared in the same way) work nice

Servlet with problem :

```
package com.myproject.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Connexion extends HttpServlet {

public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/connexion.jsp";

public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response ); 
}

public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
}
}
```

Another Servlet who works :

```
package com.myproject.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Authentification extends HttpServlet {

public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/authentification.jsp";

public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response ); 
}

public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
}
}
```

The JSP who call the servlet "Connexion" :

```
<form id="form_authentification" class="formulaire" method="post" action="connexion">
<input type="text"   class="input_text" title="<fmt:message key="mail_ou_nom" />" placeholder="<fmt:message key="mail_ou_nom" />" required />
<input type="submit" class="btn"        value="<fmt:message key="suivant" /> "/>
```

And the web.xml :

```
<!-- Authentification -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Authentification</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.servlets.Authentification</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>auteur</param-name>
        <param-value>Atyss</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Authentification</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/authentification</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Connexion -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.servlets.Connexion</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>auteur</param-name>
        <param-value>Atyss</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Connexion</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/connexion</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So If I put the method "get" in the form : "form_authentification" of the JSP authentification.jsp it works but I have in line the browser :

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/connexion?
```

Where from "?" is coming in the line browser?

If I put the method "post" in the form : "form_authentification" of the JSP authentification.jsp I have a white page for connexion.jsp and the browser tag icon of apache server.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Your `doPost` method in both Servlets doesn't do anything. I would be very surprised to hear that post method, in `Authentification` Servlet actually work.If you are going to support both GET and POST, you can call `doGet` from your `doPost` method.

Comment: For the moment I just want to dispay connexion.jsp with his form (that's why I'm using GET).I will use later POST method to validate the form.But why the line browser indicates : "http://localhost:8080/myproject/connexion?". I don't know why the question mark ends the line. When I display (through the servlet Authentification.java) autentification.jsp I dont have a question mark at the end of the browser line. It looks like this : "http://localhost:8080/myproject/authentification".

Comment: Are you using any servlet filters that add a `?`?

Comment: No, I don't know what servlet filter is. I'm novice in java

Comment: Get method always pass parameter in url so all paramater from from will be added after ? mark,here you have not given name to your input box so it will not add parameter in url and just add ?.give the name to input tag and try

Comment: You're right, I gave a name to the input and I had the parameter name in the URL. I have a question - in authentification.jsp I have also a link. If I put in this link <a href="connexion"> (Servlet context of Connexion.java servlet) I have "http://localhost:8080/myproject/connexion" in the URL. Where is the difference? The GET method in Connexion.java is unchanged and connexion.jsp is displayed normally without "?" at the end of URL